# VB.net Check next row if a value doesn't meet the requirements on Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I googled a lot and couldn't find anything.

This is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Public Class Website_a_fazer

```
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=website_tester")
Dim command As MySqlCommand

Dim WebsiteATestar As Integer = 1


Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim adapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `id_website`, `website`, `id_tipoutilizador`, `dinheiro` FROM websites WHERE id_tipoutilizador='" & Inicio.TipoUtilizador & "' AND id_website ='" & WebsiteATestar & "' AND ativo = 1", connection)
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    adapter2.Fill(table)

    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `id_websitefeito`, `id_utilizador`, `id_website`, `website` FROM websites_feitos WHERE id_utilizador='" & Inicio.IdUtilizador & "' AND id_website ='" & WebsiteATestar & "'", connection)


    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table1 As New DataTable()

    adapter.Fill(table1)



    If table1.Rows.Count = 0 Then

        Label2.Text = table(0)(1)
        Label4.Text = table(0)(3)
        Inicio.IdUrl = table(0)(0)
        Inicio.CurrentUrl = Label2.Text
        Inicio.DinheiroSite = table(0)(3)



        Dim dataSet As New DataTable
        Dim bindindsrc As New BindingSource
        Dim dataadapt As New MySqlDataAdapter



        Try

            command = New MySqlCommand("SELECT `objetivo` FROM objetivos_website WHERE id_website='" & Inicio.IdUrl & "'", connection)
            dataadapt.SelectCommand = command
            dataadapt.Fill(dataSet)
            bindindsrc.DataSource = dataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bindindsrc
            dataadapt.Update(dataSet)


        Catch ex As ArgumentException

        End Try

    Else

        WebsiteATestar = WebsiteATestar + 1


    End If


End Sub
```

This is my database:
[image: Database table "websites"]

[image: Database table "websites_feitos"]

I want to check the database on table "websites" for the first row that "id_utilizador = 4" and "ativo = 1"

If the table "websites_feitos" has already that website, check the next row of "websites", until it finds a row that meets those requirements.

Could you guys help me with this? I am making this project has a 12º year final project :)

Comment: your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** please use **prepared statemenst with parameters**

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the warning :)

Comment: mysql is not very good at selecting the next row, so het al rows and check in a loop, if you can reduce the number of rows even better

Comment: I started my project in mysql, maybe it's a little bit later to change it :D

Comment: Also, I know basics how to work in mysql, I dont know nothing about others

Comment: that doesn't matter. use yxour first select and see which rows do you want. get them(what you have, and then check all rows till it meets you requirement. it ios actually not much more code.

Comment: @VítorHugo To have a concept of "first" or "next", you will need to use "ORDER BY" on a suitable column. Otherwise, the database can return rows in a random order, because you have not told it what order you require.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks, I fixed my problem now :)